# Multi Conditional if Statement Pandas (code doesn't finish running)

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to create a multi-conditional new column in pandas based on other column values.

The following code doesn't produce an error or results (but it does produce warnings); it just keeps running:

```
for val1,val2 in zip(df['a'], df['b']):
    if val1 == 0 and val2 == 0:
        df['new_column'] = 0
    elif val1 in df['a'] == 0:
      
        df['new_column'] = 1
    else:
        for val2 in df['b']:
            if val2 ==0:
                df['new_column'] = 0
            else:
                df['new_column'] = df['b'] /  df['a']
```

df looks like:

```
['a']    ['b']
  0        0  
  0      1000
1000       0
5000     2000
```

expecting df['new column'] to be like:

```
['new column']
      0
      1
      0
     .4
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of input / expected output, and the logic

Comment: I can't say I really like using `val2` as a variable name in both the outer and inner loops here. That may be a bug.

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code. But the main issue is that a DataFrame column can't be formed in that way. See answers which show the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out what I needed specifically for what I was working on was utilizing a nested np.where statement. Defining a function and applying it wasn't yielding the correct calculation results for me.

```
df['new_column'] = np.where((df['a'] == 0) & (df['b'] == 0), 0, 
                             np.where(df['a'] == 0, 1,
                                      np.where(df['b'] ==-0, 0, df['b']/df['a']
                                              )))
```

I appreciate everyone's input.

Comment: Don't use nested `where`, use `np.select`

Comment: I will try as well...what's the rationale?

Comment: You set up the conditions and values in order of preference, rather than using nested statements

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but based on the limited information provided in the question, this code at least generates your expected output:

```
def myfunc(row):
    if row['a'] == 0 and row['b'] == 0:
        result = 0
    else:
        if row['a'] == 0:
            result = 1
        elif row['b'] == 0:
            result = 0
        else:
            result = row['b'] / row['a']
    return result

df['new column'] = df.apply(myfunc, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it generally better to define and use functions over for loops when working with data in pandas?

Comment: No, it's usually discouraged. You should use `apply` only for code that cannot be vectorized (non-vectorizable data, intrinsically iterative algorithm, I/O functions...)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a loop/`apply`, use vectorial code:

```
df['new'] = (df['b'].div(df['a'].mask(df['a'].eq(0),df['b']))
             .fillna(0)
             )
```

Output:

```
      a     b  new
0     0     0  0.0
1     0  1000  1.0
2  1000     0  0.0
3  5000  2000  0.4
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Why is vectorial code preferred over apply?

Comment: @tonytone because it's much faster (it can be several orders of magnitude faster on very large datasets). `Series.apply` and `DataFrame.apply` on `axis=1` should always be avoided when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Different in detail from @cucurbit but same principle:

```
def vals(x, y):
    if x == 0 and y == 0:
        return 0
    if x == 0 :
        return 1
    if y == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return y/x

df['new column'] = df.apply(lambda x : vals(x['a'], x['b']), axis =1)
```